# Does app update feature will work during alpha testing in android

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have published an app in play store for alpha testing in which I have uploaded an another version where I could not get any updates message stating that a new version is available. I would like to know does the app update feature will work while the app is in alpha testing.

Comment: Have you added yourself to alpha testers? Also it takes some time for alpha update to come to market.

Comment: even i have added a check for latest version but it displays me that you are using the current version but the version i having rightnow is old one.

Comment: Have you seen my first comment?

Answer (score 1):

I think this [documenation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) can help you, is stated here that if you want to run multiple tests on the same app, keep the following in mind:

- It recommend you to set up one test as a closed alpha and another as an open beta. This works because **you can run one test at a time per testing method** (e.g. open & closed).
- If you run an open alpha test, you can't use the open or closed beta track. This happens because you can't run two open tests simultaneously or run a closed beta given [version code requirements](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213#availability).

For more information, you can also check the documentaion of [Test and Publishing Game Changes](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub) of Google.